# Overriding updateParameters()-Values in Python toolbox

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.5, python-toolbox

I'm just getting started with Python toolboxes in ArcGIS and I'm pretty new to Python in general. I've created a python toolbox which

1. takes an raster input file
2. derives some values based on the *name* of the input file (via a custom function)
3. suggests several parameter values
4. processes the files in some way (not relevant to my question)

**My issue is, that I cant seem to override the suggested parameter values when I run the tool. The values always switch back to the original values as suggested via the custom function.** My guess is that whenever I change the suggested parameter, the function updateParameters() is run which in turn overrides my manual input. Is there a way to solve this dilemma?

I've reduced my toolbox (.pyt-File) to a minimal example (excluding the geoprocessing part) in the following code. In this example, the function `suggestName()` returns a new filename with the ending ".shp" and a path to the scratch folder. Imagine the function `suggestName()` to be slightly more complex and returning several values, not just one.

```
import arcpy


def suggestName(inputname):
    "Extract the Sheetnumber and Year from a given map Name"
    return inputname+".shp"


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Toolbox"""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = "Toolbox"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Some Info"""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = "Tool"
        self.canRunInBackground = False


    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """"""


        ## Raster map to extract features from
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            name = "inputRaster",
            displayName = "Inpurt Raster File (TA25)",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            datatype = "DERasterDataset"
            )


        ## Output feature class
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output Features",
            name="out_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Requred",
            direction="Output")



        return [param0,param1]



    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """"""

        if parameters[0].value:
            parameters[1].enabled = True

            newname = suggestName(arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].valueAsText).basename)


            parameters[1].value = newname
        return


    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """"""
        return
```

**Edit:**

It seems like I wasn't very clear in clarifying my issue, I'll try to do so now. As you can see in the screenshot below, the tool suggests the name "test.shp" as the output file. *But I cannot override this parameter*. If I try to do so (e.g. change the name to "test_2.shp") the parameter switches back to the original name ("test.shp") once I click anywhere outside the box.

[image: Screenshot of my tool]

Comment: I am wondering, if I understand your question corectly. If you want multiple in put you can use: params.multiValue = True or you can take a look in arcgis example here: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/multiple-values.htm

Comment: It seems I wasn't very clear with what my issue is. I've tried to explain it better by adding an *Edit:* with a screenshot. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether the answer was too obvious or my question too obscure. In any case, I've found a pragmatic solution to my problem. Add add the option "override default values?" (boolean), which when set to "true" allows manual input of the parameters without the values being updated by `updateParameters()`

Here's the final solution (see code below).
Interesting side note: `param2.value` must be set in uppercase (`True` / `False`) while `parameters[2]` returns the boolean in lower case (`true` / `false`).

```
import arcpy


def suggestName(inputname):
    "Extract the Sheetnumber and Year from a given map Name"
    return inputname+".shp"


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Toolbox"""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = "Toolbox"

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Some Info"""
        self.label = "Tool"
        self.description = "Tool"
        self.canRunInBackground = False


    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """"""


        ## Raster map to extract features from
        param0 = arcpy.Parameter(
            name = "inputRaster",
            displayName = "Inpurt Raster File (TA25)",
            parameterType = "Required",
            direction = "Input",
            datatype = "DERasterDataset"
            )


        ## Output feature class
        param1 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Output Features",
            name="out_features",
            datatype="GPFeatureLayer",
            parameterType="Requred",
            direction="Output")

        param2 = arcpy.Parameter(
            displayName="Override default values?",  
            name="override",  
            datatype="GPBoolean",  
            parameterType="Optional",  
            direction="Input"
            ) 

        param2.value = False



        return [param0,param1,param2]



    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """"""

        if parameters[0].value:
            if str(parameters[2].valueAsText) == "false":
                newname = suggestName(arcpy.Describe(parameters[0].valueAsText).basename)

                parameters[1].value = newname
        return


    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        print(parameters[2].valueAsText)
        """"""
        return
```